# How to create n threads and work with all of them

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

Im trying to create a given number of threads and treat them at the same time to make a "race" program. The threads are created but im doing something wrong because any of the threads prints "Hi".

```
public class Principal implements Runnable{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int howManyThreads = 3;
        Thread thread[];

        thread = new Thread[howManyThreads];

        for ( int i=0; i < thread.length; i++ ){

            thread[i]= new Thread();
            thread[i].setName("Thread - " + i);
        }

        for ( int i=0; i < thread.length; ++i){

            thread[i].start();
            System.out.println(thread[i].getName() + " - " + thread[i].getState());
        }

    }

    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be instantiating `Principal` instead of `Thread`?

Comment: @lcssanches You can't create a thread without creating an instance of `Thread` or, of some class that inherits from `Thread`. The `Principal` class in this example could be changed to `extends Thread`, but see my answer, below for cleaner ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default constructor for the `Thread` class creates a thread that does nothing. You're calling that default constructor here:  `thread[i] = new Thread();`

If you want the thread to actually do something, then you must provide a `Runnable` instance as an argument to the Thread constructor. There are a couple of ways to do that. The newest, most concise way is to use a *lambda expression*:

```
thread[i] = new Thread(() -> {
    System.out.println("Hi");
});
```

The `Runnable` interface is an [`@FunctionalInterface`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/functional-interfaces-java/). Since the compiler knows that the `Thread(...)` constructor wants an object of that type, it infers that that's what the lambda should create, and the body of the lambda becomes the `run()` method of the new object.

---

Another, older way to provide a `Runnable` object is to use an *anonymous inner class* expression.  The syntax is a little more cumbersome because you have to explicitly say what interface the new class should implement, and you have to explicitly declare the `run()` method:

```
thread[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
});
```

---

The oldest way, still even more verbose, is to explicitly declare a named class:

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
};

public class Principal /*does not need to implement Runnable*/ {
    ...
    thread[i] = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
    ...
}
```

You might ask, why did I remove `implements Runnable` from the `Principal` class, and create a whole new class?

I did it because, I've read this book: [https://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)